# alert_message cannot be put in strategy.entry :-(

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am new here :-) I hope that you will understand my message because I have never done any code :'-)
So, I want to connect my tradingview strategy with my 3commas bot through the alert webhook of tradingview. However, I tried putting the message fot the bot like in the script bellow be I have the error : "no viable alternative at character '{'". So I tried th change "comment=" to "alert_message=" but there is this error :Cannot call `strategy.entry` with arguments (literal__string, bool, literal__string); available overloads: strategy.entry(literal__string, series__bool, series, series, series, string, literal__string, string, series__bool) => void;"
I woul really appreciate some help if you have the time, thanks in advance !

```
// Strategy
if (not na(k) and not na(d))
          if (crossover(k,d) and k < OverSold and crossover(delta, 0)) 
          strategy.entry("Entrylong", strategy.long, comment="{\n\"message_type\": \"bot\",\n\"bot_id\": xxxxxxx,\n\"email_token\": \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\",\n\"delay_seconds\": 0\n}")
    
           if (crossunder(k,d) and k > OverBought and crossunder(delta, 0))
           strategy.entry("Entryshort", strategy.short, comment="{\n\"message_type\": \"bot\",\n\"bot_id\": xxxxxxx,\n\"email_token\": \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\",\n\"delay_seconds\": 0\n}")
```

Comment: Is this how your indentation look like?

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible code that compiles?

Answer (score 1):

This is the example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = bar_index%2 == 0 and barstate.isrealtime
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, alert_message = '{\n"message_type": "bot",\n"bot_id": xxxxxxx,\n "email_token": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",\n"delay_seconds": 0\n}')

shortCondition = bar_index%2 == 1 and barstate.isrealtime
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, alert_message = '{\n"message_type": "bot",\n"bot_id": yyyyyyy,\n "email_token": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",\n"delay_seconds": 0\n}')
```

[image]